# Mapper Only Output Issue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to get an output from a Mapreduce job which we get easily from a Hive query. I have a dataset :

### ID , color, rate

1,  blue,  200
2,  green, 170
3,  yellow, 400
4,  yellow, 230
5,  green, 140
6,  red, 542
7,  green, 43
8,  blue, 228
9,  red,190

Now i want only those rows in output whose rate is more than 200. so for this the Query in Hive will be pretty straight :

### select id, color, rate from table_name where rate > 200;

Now for this I am trying MapReduce code in which i think only the Mapper is enough to get the desired output. But not able to figure out Mapper output ..

### HiveMapper

```
public class HiveMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String [] line = value.toString().split(",");

        if(Integer.parseInt(line[2]) > 200) {
            System.out.println(line[0] + "," + line[1] + "," + line[2]);
            context.write(new Text(line[0] + "," + line[1] + ",") , new Text(line[2]) );
            //context
        }

    }

}
```

### HiveDriver

```
public class HiveDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = new Job(conf,"Mapreduce in Hive");

        job.setJarByClass(HiveDriver.class);
        job.setMapperClass(HiveMapper.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        //int ss = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
        //System.out.println(ss);
    }

}
```

### Current Output

```
0       1,blue,200
12      2,green,170
25      3,yellow, 400
40      4,yellow, 230
55      5,green, 140
69      6,red, 542
81      7,green, 43
94      8,blue, 228
107     9,red,190
```

### Expected Output

3,yellow, 400
4,yellow, 230
6,red, 542
8,blue, 228

Answer (score 1):

Your map function is not being used by the Map Task.
Instead it is using its default implementation for the map function.
This is happening because the key type is not the same in the Class declaration and the function argument.
In the class declaration you have **K-> LongWritable**, but in the function you have **Key Text**.

Since the types are not the same, your map function implementation does not override the default implementation.

The correct Signature for your map function should be:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
```

Comment: But when i tried changing the datatype in Class argument and in map function <i.e> Both as TEXT, i am getting the same old output

0       1,blue,200
12      2,green,170
25      3,yellow, 400
40      4,yellow, 230
55      5,green, 140
69      6,red, 542
81      7,green, 43
94      8,blue, 228
107     9,red,190

Can we actually override the Class definition & Map function if yes then how and how the map function will read the next line as an input split

Comment: You can choose a different type for the input key and value. As you can see in this [example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) the key is an Object in the class definition and the map function.

Comment: I am using Text class in class definition & map function definition also but then why it is working properly with LongWritable and not with TEXT class. Is it something related to input split which is a single row of data by default